# AKS Networking using CNI network method

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy AKS with CNI but as soon as I create vnet and subnet it stops write there with the error that I do not have permission to create it.

I have contributor access to the entire subscription, but it looks like this is one odd resource that requires owner permission when I am using CNI for network deployment.

trying to deploy AKS with contributor access and I was hoping to get it deployed successfully